# Why is `android:maxLines` ignored when I apply it indirectly via `TextAppearance`

Tags: android, textview, styles

Why is `android:maxLines` ignored when I apply it indirectly via `TextAppearance`

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.Footer">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
  </style>

  <style name="FooterButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Footer</item>
  </style>
```

I see nothing about textAppearance restrictions in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance)

It works when i set the attribute directly:

```
  <style name="FooterButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Apply the `android:maxLines` to the View as `TextView`, `Button`, not to the `TextAppearance`

Comment: @Gab yes, but why?

Comment: Check the @Froyo answer. The attribute android:maxLines is not managed in the android:maxLines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The document does not specify any restrictions. But given that it's android documentation, it's going to lack a lot of details. From the source code, following attributes can be set via `textAppearance`.

```
    int mTextColorHighlight = 0;
    ColorStateList mTextColor = null;
    ColorStateList mTextColorHint = null;
    ColorStateList mTextColorLink = null;
    int mTextSize = 0;
    String mFontFamily = null;
    Typeface mFontTypeface = null;
    boolean mFontFamilyExplicit = false;
    int mTypefaceIndex = -1;
    int mStyleIndex = -1;
    int mFontWeight = -1;
    boolean mAllCaps = false;
    int mShadowColor = 0;
    float mShadowDx = 0, mShadowDy = 0, mShadowRadius = 0;
    boolean mHasElegant = false;
    boolean mElegant = false;
    boolean mHasFallbackLineSpacing = false;
    boolean mFallbackLineSpacing = false;
    boolean mHasLetterSpacing = false;
    float mLetterSpacing = 0;
    String mFontFeatureSettings = null;
```

There is **mStyleIndex**, but it's the text style - `bold`, `italic`, etc.

You will have to set that via `style` or `android:maxLines` in the xml.

As a justification for the choice, I could say that number of lines does not fall in the criteria of text appearance but rather the style of the view.